# Distinguising between the cases of low or high cover number

Tags: approximation-hardness

Is there a known result saying that for some constants $0 < a < b < 1$, it is NP-hard to distinguish a graph having vertex cover number at most $a \cdot n$ from a graph having vertex cover number at least $b \cdot n$? Here n is the number of vertices in the input graph. In other words, I want to know that (unless P = NP) there is no poly-time algorithm that accepts graphs with vertex-cover number at most $a \cdot n$, rejects graphs with vertex-cover number at least $b \cdot n$, and can return anything for a graph whose vertex-cover number is in between.

Answer (score 5):

Proving hardness of this sort of gap problem is usually how hardness of approximation is proved. For vertex cover, Håstad's famous [paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=502098) (Theorem 7.1.) showed what you are asking for with $a=3/4$ and $b=7/8$.